# prove that $(x_k)$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Please, tell me if my solution to the following problem is correct:

" If $(x_k)$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ and $(x_k)$ has only one adherent point, prove that $(x_k)$ is convergent".

Solution: Since $(x_k)$ has only one adherent point, then $\exists  \mathbb N' \subset \mathbb N$, such that $\lim _{k \in \mathbb N'} x_k = a$. But $k \in \mathbb N' \Rightarrow k \in \mathbb N$. Then $\lim_{k \in \mathbb N} x_k = a$, i.e., $(x_k)$ is convergent. Thank you.

Comment: Could you expand what you mean in this part "But $k \in \mathbb N' \Rightarrow k \in \mathbb N$. Then $\lim_{k \in \mathbb N} x_k = a$"

Comment: @Walter, I'm afraid you proved that if a sequence has one converging subsequence then the whole sequence converges and to the same limit as the subsequence...which, of course, is false.

Comment: As I understand what you said, this is incorrect.  Consider $(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, ...)$.  There is a subsequence converging to $1$ and one to $-1$ but certainly the sequence does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct. You need to use the boundedness and "only one adherent point" condition.

Note by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, any bounded sequence of $(x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence, say $x_{n_k}\to x$. Hence $x$ is an adherent point of $(x_n)$. We then prove the sequence converges to $x$.

Suppose not, $\exists \epsilon>0$, and subsequence $x_{n_j}$ s.t. $||x_{n_j}-x||>\epsilon$. Since $x_{n_j}$ is also bounded, we have a convergent subsequence, which given $(x_n)$ another adherent point $z\neq x$ (since $x_{n_j}$ is bounded away from $x$ by $\epsilon$). Thus we get a contradiction.

Hence $(x_n) \to x$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is incorrect. The boundedness is important and you do not use it.

HINT: If $(x_k)$ is bounded and there are infinitely many $x_k$'s outside $(g-\varepsilon,g+\varepsilon)$, where $g$ is the adherent point, at least one additional adherent point must exist.

Answer (score 1):

use this: a sequence is convergent to $x$ if and only if every subsequence has a sub-subsequence that converges to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is false. You cannot directly infer from the fact that a subsequence converges that the sequence converges. The converse would work though.